# water filter for shower boiler

Tags: water, shower, filter

In a shared garden, I have access to a pipe where the water comes from a well. the water is already pre-filtered but still contains (small amount) particles.

I would like to install a shower, the few particles would not be an issue for the shower, but I need to install a water boiler and I am concerned that the particles would then drastically reduce the life of the boiler.

I could find lot of water filters on-line but they are all focused on making the water more drinkable which is not my goal.

Is my worry justified, and a water filter is definitely required?
if yes what type filter should I better use for an economical and quality shower? (I do not have to make the water drinkable)

Comment: Also be sure to flush your water heater bi annually it will extend its life and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is typically referred to as a "whole home water filter".  The name isn't the best description of what it is, but basically they are high-volume water filters that only filter out sediment and relatively large particulate.  They do not bring water to a "drinking water" quality but do filter out anything that would be harmful to appliances.

The good news for you is that they can be cheap enough for a simple installation like yours:

[image]

Image from:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Whole-Home-Water-Filtration-System-GXWH04F/100471282

Only $20, which is a low enough price to put it into the "why not" category.  If you have any reason to believe the water might have some sediment it in, that's enough justification to use one.

To replace the filter, the whole bottom part screws off and a new filter cartridge is put in.  This model says to replace the filter every 3 months, but with your low volume it would probably last much longer.

Comment: Very useful! But there are a few choices for the corresponding filters I can chose. Do you maybe have some recommendation for it?

Comment: The type of filter really has more to do with what your expected incoming water quality is.  Read what each filter type claims to do, and choose based on what you expect.  They will get more expensive and may be more restrictive based on how much they filter out.  Since you are only driving one shower from it, more restrictive should matter.  Cost is probably your most important consideration because it sounds like your water quality needs are not very demanding either.